# Density of free particle energy eigenfunctions in 1d for periodic boundary conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The energy spectrum for the above, subject to the periodic boundary conditions such that the eigenfunctions are have a period of $L$, is given by
$$E_n = E_0n^2, \qquad n=0, \pm1, \pm2, \ldots$$
where $E_0 = (2\pi^2\hbar^2)/(mL^2)$. Each $E\neq0$ is doubly degenerate.

Then to find the density of states, I observe that $E_{n+1}-E_n = E_0(2n+1)\approx 2E_0n=2\sqrt{E_0E_n}$. Since there's double degeneracy, I conclude that the energy density at energy $E$ is
$$\frac{2}{2\sqrt{E_0E}}=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}\frac{L}{\pi\hbar}.$$

But Merzbacher in his *Quantum Mechanics* says that it should be
$$\sqrt{\frac{2m}{E}}\frac{L}{\pi\hbar}.$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is there any restriction on $n$? Seems like the degeneracy might not exist

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish No, $n$ can be any integer.